# Scrapy + Selenium mixed code makes an error

Tags: javascript, php, python, selenium, scrapy

I was about to scrape a webpage which is loaded with javascript and PHP.
So I mixed Scrapy code with Selenium. But due to the reason I don't know, 
the code keeps making error.

The page I want to scrape is http://ntry.com/#/scores/named_ladder/main.php,
which can be reached by clicking a button whose text element is u"사다리", from
**ntry.com**. I used firefox Selenium Plugin and recorded entering the ntry.com, clicking the button, reaching the page to be scraped, and used the code which went out from the recording.

So, I made a spider file mixed with selenium code.

```
# encoding=utf-8
import unittest, time, re
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

class NTRYSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ntryspider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.ntry.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://ntry.com"
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        scrapy.Spider.__init__(self)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):

        self.driver.get(response.url + "/#/main.php")
        self.driver.find_element_by_link_text(u"사다리").click()
        time.sleep(5)

        html =self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*').get_attribute('outerHTML')
    print html
    display.stop()
```

and This makes ERROR like this:

`File "/home/ubuntu/ntry_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ntry_virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: \uc0ac\ub2e4\ub9ac`

Not only related to the Error message, Are there any possible problem in the code above? 
and what element am I missing? What should I do?

I am using headless Ubuntu 14.04 with latest and compatible pyvirtualdisplay, xvfb, firefox, webdriver, .. etc..

Btw, the firefox selenium plugin generated code is like below :sweat_smile:

```
class PythonNtry(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://ntry.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_python_ntry(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/#/main.php")
        # ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectFrame | contentFrame | ]]
        driver.find_element_by_link_text(u"사다리").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is faulty:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text(u"사다리").click()
```

`find_element_by_link_text()` returns a selenium web object if it can be found, otherwise it returns `None`. What is happening here is that no element is found and you call `click()` on it. To fix that you can safe-wrap this into:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text(u"사다리")
if element: 
    element.click()
else:
    print('element not found!')
```